# Making an android dialog as simple as a toast?

Tags: android

I know there is a very easy way to make a `Toast` appear in your android application, for example, like so...

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Please select a contact to delete!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                return true;
```

Upon reading some documentation, I've found that making a  simple yes or no `Dialog` appear can be done in multiple ways and is generally longer.

My question is, what is the simplest way a simple a dialog can be made. For example, `Are you sure you want to delete this file?` with buttons `Yes` or `No`.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog . They do some simple alert dialogs. Probably the easiest way. If you end up wanting to customize your own dialog, then it becomes a bit more longer.

Comment: Make sure you wrap the `AlertDialog` in a `DialogFragment` (or use the deprecated `Activity#showDialog()` method, but you really shouldn't anymore) to ensure your dialog is able to survive configuration changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply message box

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidAlertDialog.this);
myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Title ---");
myAlertDialog.setMessage("Alert Dialog Message");
myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
// do something when the OK button is clicked
}});
myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
// do something when the Cancel button is clicked
}});
myAlertDialog.show();
```

cheers..

Comment: selected this answer because it has the onclick methods. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use `AlertDialog.Builder` as mentioned by others:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(...);
  builder.setTitle(title)
         .setMessage(...)
         .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... })
         .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

This can be trivially wrapped in a factory method so that you can construct a dialog with a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is go with `AlertDialog` and `AlertDialog.Builder`. Each Activity has a `ShowDialog` function, however this function is deprecated since API 13.